# Cambiar el nombre de archivos en dos directorios diferentes

Tags: laravel

Tengo el código que funciona para cambiar el nombre de un archivo en un directorio, ahora necesito cambiar el nombre del mismo archivo en dos directorios diferentes.

Con el primer if(Storage)... Funciona bien, con el segundo me dice que ya el nombre del archivo existe por lo que pienso que no busca en el segundo directorio.

```
if (strcmp($oldFileName, $newFileName) !== 0) 
    { 

        if( Storage::disk('image')->exists($photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension) )
        {
            Storage::disk('image')->move($photo->year.'/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $photo->year.'/'.$newFileName.'.'.$extension);
        }

        if( Storage::disk('image')->exists($photo->year.'/download/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension) )
        {
            Storage::disk('image')->move($photo->year.'/download/'.$oldFileName.'.'.$extension, $photo->year.'/'.$newFileName.'.'.$extension);
        }

    }
```

Comment: El archivo que ya existe es el que tiene el nombre que le quieres poner, pues en la línea anterior ya le pusiste ese nombre a otro archivo

Comment: entiendo, pensé que podría pornerles el mismo nombre porque están en directorios diferente

Comment: El directorio de destino es el mismo.

Comment: Disculpa, segunda vez que me pasa, de hecho me lo habías corregido tú. Mil gracias!

Comment: funciona perfecto, muchas gracias.